# INDEX MATCH formula Google Sheet returns N/A value

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in Google Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqTUjoT978AyNU7TeBfVbcWDQ_aAamC7d51UB8gdLBk/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to get "ranking" value from previous day ranking sheet.
Currently I am shucked with INDEX MATCH formula to get data from previous date sheet (20210810-0:7).
Please have a look at "20210811-0:6" sheet row 24, the formula I made returns N/A value
I tried VLOOKUP and combinations of INDEX MATCH formulas but all failed.
I checked the content D column with D column in another sheet, all values returned "TRUE"
Please tell me my mistakes. I tried many combinations of below formula.

=INDEX('20210810-0:7'!A4:A29,match(D24,'20210810-0:7'!A4:G29,0))

Yellow highlight is mistake formula
Green is how it should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=FILTER('20210810-0:7'!$A$4:$A$29,'20210810-0:7'!$D$4:$D$29 = D24)

Paste this in B24, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: YES! It worked perfectly and does what I wanted ! Thank you for your time and efforts Alistair McEvoy . I am sorry that could not upvote. Not enough reputations.

Comment: @Above Themess if you found that this answered your question, consider accepting by hitting the checkmark next to it